# Rails: three-way has_many/through relationship: prevent duplicate join items creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Here is an extract of the models I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :groups, through: :participations
  has_many :subgroups, through: :participations
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
  has_many :subgroups
end

class Subgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :user
  belongs_to: :group
  belongs_to: :subgroup

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :group, presence: true
  # Subgroup can be empty, as long as user as not been placed.

  # There should be only one participation per couple User:Group
  validates_uniqueness_of :group_id, :scope => [:user_id]

  # Also has a state-machine, describing the participation status.
end
```

Explanation: groups are split in subgroups, users select the group they join, but not the subgroup, which is selected later by an administrator. 
When a User is added to a Group (`group_a.users << user_a`), a Participation is automatically created by ActiveRecord.
I would like the same participation to be reused when the same User is added to a Subgroup of that Group (`subgroup_1.users << user_a` with `subgroup_1` a Subgroup of `group_a`'s).

What happens actually is ActiveRecord trying to create a new Participation record, which conflicts with the previously created one (`validates_uniqueness_of :group_id, :scope => [:user_id]`
 fires an error).

Is there anyway I could make this work? I tried hooking before_validation, before_save, and some other stuff, but every attempt failed.

Maybe there is a better way to actually model this relationship?

Any help is welcome.

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 1):

You could DRY up all of your code by instead calling

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :groups, through: :participations
  has_many :subgroups, through: :groups # HMT -> HMT
end
```

Would this solve your problem? This **probably** won't scale, but we'll worry about that later :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure it would work though, or maybe I don't understand your suggestion.
Each subscribing user is placed in a group on subscription, but no subgroup. Later, when subscriptions end for this group, an administrator creates many subgroups for this group, and then places each user in one of these subgroups.

In that context, I'm afraid I can't see how `has_many :subgroups, through: :groups` would work. Am I missing something?